# Initialize new c++ array with different specified values

Tags: c++, arrays

I am able to initialize an array with default values

```
int arrayWithDefault[5] = { 0 };
```

Also able to initialize new array with default values

```
int *ptrArrayWithDefault = new int[2]();
```

How can i initialize a new array with different values such that

```
ptrArrayWithDefault[0] == 1 && ptrArrayWithDefault[1] == 2
```

I can simply solve it with

```
int arrayWithDefault[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

but i was wondering if there is a way to initialize new array in such way?

Comment: You should avoid raw owning pointers btw.

Comment: You can use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `std::iota(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 1);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki That's not initialisation.

Comment: @molbdnilo maybe because it can't be done in initialization (at least not for plain arrays) ?

Comment: one can use `std::array` instead [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbcad39bd752dab4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really avoid such a scenario and follow proper practices.
However, I was able to do similar task using

```
int *ptr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

and with this way

```
ptr[0] = 1 
  .
  .
  .
ptr[4] = 5
```